# Cannot Access 'COUNT(id)' from RowDataPacket, after executing 'SELECT COUNT' query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to access the variable which contains the actual number of counted elements, but I don't know how.

```
    sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE username='" + req.body.username + "' AND password='" + req.body.password + "';";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    })
```

The `result` is: `[ RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(id)': 0 } ]` ; I cannot access data by using the syntax result.COUNT(id), because I get the error: `ReferenceError: id is not defined`

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) as Cnt .....` then `result.Cnt`

Comment: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual th
at corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS
 Cnt' at line 1

Comment: Ok, it finally worked. I misspelled some letters, that's why it didn't work for the first time...

Comment: write query as @RiggsFolly suggested and don't concat username and password use ? and query array

Answer (score 1):

Use alias for `count` and for better abstraction use template literals in your query

```
 sql = `SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM users WHERE username=${req.body.username}  AND password=${req.body.password}`;
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
    })
```

> And For [ RowDataPacket { 'total': 0 } ]  ,try this

```
     sql = `SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM users WHERE username=${req.body.username}  AND password=${req.body.password}`;
            con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                  else{
let results=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)) // gives you an js object array
    } })
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this late answer but I hope my answer help other people too, to access the value of `COUNT(id)` or in your example the value **0**, instead of using `result.COUNT(id)` you can declare a new variable , for example **data**, and use this:

```
let data = result[0]['COUNT(id)'];
```

If the key of object use character like ( ), you can use square bracket, for example: `['*key_name*']` , to access the value. The index [0] is needed because your variable *result* is an array. The `RowDataPacket` is the name of the constructor function that creates an object.

Answer (score 0):

Give your field an Alias (label)

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM users WHERE username='" + req.body.username + "' AND password='" + req.body.password + "';";
```

the result will be `[ RowDataPacket { 'total': 0 } ]`